# What's the point of hardcoded class properties in Vue Options API/

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

Is there a point to defining properties like var_B when using Vue Options API? They are not reachable when defining methods, or inside the template tags. I'm aware I can define variables inside data() for those purposes, but I'm wondering why Vue allows this at all, and if there exists a practical use case

```
<script>
export default {
  var_B: 10, // WHY DEFINE PROPERTIES HERE AT ALL?
  data() {
    return {
      var_A: 9, 
    };
  },
  methods: {
    double() {
      this.var_A = this.var_A * var_B;
      // causes 9 x undefined  = NaN
    },
  },
};
</script>

<template lang="">
  <div>Variable A: {{ var_A }}</div> <!-- 9 -->
  <div>Variable B: {{ var_B }}</div> <!-- undefined -->
  <button @click="double">Try to Double var_A</button>
</template>
```

I attempted to use the hardcoded class properties inside the template tags, and inside a method, neither of which worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data()` is a reactive object. It is being watched by Vue for changes and, should any of the values declared in the object returned by  `data()` change, Vue will update all places where it is used (`computed`, `methods`, template).

Declaring custom properties on the base export of a Vue (`var_b` in your example) ***is invalid***. The application won't error, but nothing you put there is available under `this.` (or in the template).

If you want a simple constant read when the component is parsed and don't care about Vue watching it for changes, place it in the root of the `<script>`:

```js
const b = 10
export default {
  data: () => ({
    a: 5
  }),
  computed: {
    c() { return this.a * b }
  }
}
```

Whenever you change `a`, `c` will automatically become current value of `this.a` * `b`.